# UIScrollView with paging enable not working properly

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, ios14

Trying to add four `UIView`'s in `UIScrollView`

**The issue is next (2, 3, and 4) view gets a bit off from the visible screen view when scroll.**

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    configureSlider()
  }

private func configureSlider() {
        Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CarouselSliderView", owner: self, options: nil)
        addSubview(contentView)
      
        for i in 0...3 {
          let view = UIView()
          
          switch i {
          case 0:
            view.backgroundColor = .brown
          case 1:
            view.backgroundColor = .yellow
          case 2:
            view.backgroundColor = .green
          case 3:
            view.backgroundColor = .blue
          default:
            view.backgroundColor = .red
          }
          
          slides.append(view)
        }
        
        setupSlideScrollView(slides: slides)
        pageControl.numberOfPages = slides.count
        pageControl.currentPage = 0
        self.bringSubviewToFront(pageControl)
      }
```

set each UIView frames:

```
private func setupSlideScrollView(slides : [UIView]) {
    
    let screenRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
    let screenWidth = screenRect.size.width

    for i in 0 ..< slides.count {
      slides[i].frame = CGRect(x: screenWidth * CGFloat(i), y: 0, width: screenWidth, height: self.frame.height)
      topScrollView.addSubview(slides[i])
    }
    
    topScrollView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenWidth, height: self.frame.height)
    topScrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: screenWidth * CGFloat(slides.count), height: self.frame.height)

  }


func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let pageIndex = round(scrollView.contentOffset.x/self.frame.width)
    pageControl.currentPage = Int(pageIndex)
  }
```

[image]

Comment: I think you don't need to set content size.

Comment: @RajaKishan then how it'll scroll?

Comment: It takes content size automatically as per subview.

Comment: still not works

Comment: @HarshalWani - first issue, you don't show your initialization code, but you are almost certainly calling it from the wrong place. Second, you will be much better off (for a number of reasons) if you use auto-layout instead of trying to calculate rectangles.